# Why is this label's text not totally transparent?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, transparent

I am trying to display a label on a form where the form is transparent.

I am getting an outline around the label's text as seen in the below image:

[image]

The black is the background of a different form.

Here is my form code:

```
label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.White;
TopMost = true;
```

How can I display the label without the white as seen in the above image?

Comment: That's normal, the text is anti-aliased.  Pixels close to the letters are various shades of red.  Not pure white and therefore not transparent.  You cannot use a Label if you want to do this, you'll have to paint it yourself.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609520/how-to-make-text-labels-smooth). It will help!

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned a link in the comments. Then I tried it as well. It works. Check out the screenshot below. The first text is from the general Label while the second one is from the CustomLabel from [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609520/how-to-make-text-labels-smooth).

[image]

Just to summarize what needs to be done, I would quote from that post itself. We need to create a CustomLabel class inheriting from System.Windows.Forms.Label:

```
public partial class CustomLabel : Label
{
    private TextRenderingHint _hint = TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;   
    public TextRenderingHint TextRenderingHint
    {
        get { return this._hint; }
        set { this._hint = value; }
    }        

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {            
        pe.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint;
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

We would then build this and this CustomLabel would appear in Toolbox for us to use it. After dragging it onto our form we need to set its **TextRenderingHint** property to **AntiAlias**