# C# Form Difference in text display

Tags: c#, winforms, label, revit-api

I am making an addin for a modelling program called Revit.
In my addin several UI elements will be used and I want them to look exactly like the UI's of Revit.
I have found the font Revit uses and which size but the UI of Revit has some blue and yellow around the letters. (see picture). The font used is Segoe UI, 9pt.

Now my question is how do I make my text exactly the same as Revit's?
In the picture below you see the difference.
The top one is Revit's and the bottom one is mine.
I have used labels to create the text.

[image: text comparison]

Comment: I think that's antialiasing. Anyway, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609520/how-to-make-text-labels-smooth) works.

Comment: You may want to use WPF rather than WinForms

Answer (score 0):

For "simple" forms, make sure check the many possibilities of the TaskDialog Class.

[Link here](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/853afb57-7455-a636-9881-61a391118c16.htm)